# Qt: Font agnostic text bounding rect

Tags: c++, qt

I'm drawing messages in a message feed of a messenger.

By design first I need to understand how much space each message is going to take, and only then, may be only those that are visible are actually going to be displayed.

I use `QFontMetrics::boundingRect` method to get text size now.

Everything works perfectly while the text contains symbols that present in current font. As soon as someone introduces some missing in the current font glyphs, lets say from Chinese or Japanese char sets the calculations become wrong and I can understand why - my fontMetrics basically has no idea of those glyphs and probably measure them as some placeholder or that quare sign.

My question: what is the correct way to measure the text in font agnostic way? Meaning that the calculations of the text would take to account all of the algorithms the system is going to apply rendering the same text?

This is a performance critical piece, I would like to avoid solutions like creating a QLabel and requesting its size.

Comment: Does qt actually draw those symbols but compute a 0 width?

Comment: Now, it does compute some size but it's not exactly correct, new lines are computed in a wrong way and some text is out of visible bounds after it's displayed. Theoretically, I think, I can request system fonts from the system, get measures from all of them, query each glyph from my metrics to until I find the font that had that symbol and summarize the result, but it feels like there shall be a better way...

Comment: Try `tightBoundingRect` first.

Comment: The documentation also suggests this:
"If you want to know the advance width of the string (to lay out a set of strings next to each other), use horizontalAdvance() instead."

Comment: well, basically, my problem is with height. The wrapping is done and calculated correctly, Just the last line gets cut in half if the lines are more then 5. Looks like that method doesn't take to account extended line height of my Chinese font.
I can't use tightBoundingRect - I have restricted width, I also can't use horizontalAdvance - this is not what I need to calculate